# Python/Numpy: Efficiently store non-sparse large symmetric arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, storage

I am trying to store data on my hard drive that comes in the form of 2 million symmetric 100x100  matrices. Almost all elements of these matrices are non-zero. I am currently saving this data in 200 npy files; each of which has size 5.1GB and contains 100000x100x100 numpy array. This takes up more than 1TB of hard drive space.

Is there anyway that I can use the fact that the matrices are symmetric to save space on my hard drive?

Comment: Seems like those are 3D arrays. Give us a minimal sample case, just to see the kind of symmetry we are talking about?

Comment: You can write your own class which only stores one triangular part (+ diag) in a flattened form (while storing the flattening-order Fortran vs. C (maybe not needed; can't wrap my head around currently); part of numpy-array). But if you are using compression (savez_compressed) during saving, i expect it to be nearly as efficient (guessing). At least for smaller arrays as compression is probably typical LZW-like using some window-size.

Comment: (Maybe the LZW-window-argument is irrelevant as for exploiting symmetry-only opposed to inter-value correlations we would only need entropy-coding like Huffman/AC. It's easy to check the ratio for yourself though.)

Comment: @sascha I am currently just using `numpy.save()`. The documentation for `numpy.save()` doesn't mention anything about compression. So I assume it is not compressed?

Comment: I would think so (the API is somewhat unintuitive). But as i said: easy to check!

Comment: OK, I'll check the documentation for savez_compressed and give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Do that. Then you can do the same for the triangular-approach easily (no need to implement a complete bijective class for first trial). Compression might allow some savings from other correlations than symmetry. Without that, the triangular-approach allows a closed-form calculation of the needed bytes (without testing).

Comment: scipy distance pdist calculations return a `condensed` form, and can switch between that and `squareform`.  Condensed is the triangular values as 1d.

Comment: @hpaulj That is a very cool idea. It is not applicable to my data because `squareform` requires matrices to have only zeros on the diagonal (which is not true for my data). However, if my matrices had empty diagonals, it would reduce the required storage space. (I just tested it and it would bring me down from 3.5GB to 2.4GB.)

Comment: @Alice Schwarze, out of interest what did you go with?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Sascha's suggestions to use savez_compressed did the trick for me, so I didn't try the other suggestions. I've met people who complained that HDF takes long to read, so I wanted to try to solve my problem within the scope of numpy first.

Comment: @AliceSchwarze, great, good to know. i might play around with `savez_compressed` next time.

Answer (score 2):

To store only the upper half of the matrix (including the diagonal) you should be able to do something like:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.load([filename])

flat = []
for a in data:
    flat.append(a[np.triu_indices(100)])

np.savez([filename], *flat)
```

And then to load them back:

```
import numpy as np

flat = np.load([filename])

data = []

for name, a in flat:
    arr = np.zeros((100,100),dtype=[dtype])
    arr[np.triu_indices(100)] = a
    arr = arr + arr.T - np.diag(arr.diagonal)
    data.append(arr)

data = np.array(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider HDF5. There are many options for compression via h5py python library. Two of the most popular are lzf (fast decompression, moderate compression ratio) and gzip (slower decompression, good compression ratio). With gzip, you can choose compression level. In addition, gzip and lzf allow shuffle filters to improve compression ratios.

For dense arrays of uncompressed size ~8GB (csv), I typically see 75% reduction after applying lzf in HDF5. I don't expect so large a benefit from npy to HDF5, but it could still be significant.

Another benefit is HDF5 supports lazy reading. In python you can do this directly through [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) or via [dask.array](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array.html).

If you wish to go down this route, [h5py documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage) has sample high-level code.

**Disclaimer**: I have no affiliation with h5py or dask. I just find these libraries useful for high-level data analysis.